# Do NOT create new record when exact match is not found Live Agent?

Tags: liveagent

Is it possible to NOT create a new record when an exact match isn't found in Salesforce when an end-user initiates a chat via Live Agent? We have a situation where it's 95% likely that person is in Salesforce, but an exact match is unlikely for a few reasons. We don't want our agents to have to close out the create a new contact tab each time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possbile using findOrCreate.map.isExactMatch.

```
<input type= "hidden" name= "liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch: String entityName" value= "String fieldName, Boolean exactMatch;" />
```

Refer to the documentation at 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_creating_records_prechat_API_isExactMatch.htm